# How to identify from javascript a browser tab tear-off in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser-tab

Is there a way to identify in my javascript that a browser tab is dragged off and dropped to start a new browser instance (A.K.A. tear-off)?

Comment: There is none I'm aware of. But why do you want to detect this event? May be we can suggest something else that'd work for you.